# "Failed to resolve T[] modreq(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsVolatile)"

Tags: c#, cil, mono.cecil

The following error message was reported by a user:

`Failed to resolve T[] modreq(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsVolatile)`

This is the offending line of code:

```
public static TypeDefinition ResolveTypeReference(this TypeReference typeReference)
{
    return typeReference.Resolve() ?? throw new ResolutionException(typeReference);
}
```

**This method is invoked on operands of instructions whose opcodes are either `OpCodes.Ldfld` or `OpCodes.Ldobj`.**

`ResolutionException` is a class in the `MonoCecil` library:

```
public ResolutionException(MemberReference member)
  : base("Failed to resolve " + member.FullName)
{
  if (member == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (member));
  this.member = member;
}
```

I.e., the value of the `FullName` property of the offending `TypeReference` is `T[] modreq(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsVolatile)`.

Unfortunately I don't have more of the stack trace to share, so pardon me for the vague questions:

1. In what scenarios is the `FullName` property of a `TypeReference` set to `T[] modreq(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsVolatile)`?
2. Is its unresolvability due to the same reason that it has that particular `Fullname`, or is it due to some other cause?
3. Can you provide some sample C# code that decompiles into something that has **exactly** that full name? When I decompile the following code [inside SharpLab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgZgATIEzoMIB4AVAPnQG8BYAKHVswwDcB7CAQ2EgFN1CBtAXXQAzMJwgwA3NTrppdNJgAs6ALIAKAJTk5M2g1YAndME4BbAA7oAvMNHipNOgF9qToA),

```
public class C<T> 
{
    public volatile T[] field;

    public void M() 
    {
        var temp = field;
    }
}
```

the instruction of interest is

```
IL_0004: ldfld !0[] modreq([System.Private.CoreLib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsVolatile) class C`1<!T>::'field'
```

`!0[]` is used to represent a generic array, rather than `T[]`. This motivates my first question.

Comment: Looks like a bug/limitation in Cecil, then. The `modreq` expresses that `field` is `volatile`, which needs to be passed along to methods to ensure the JIT will only generate `volatile.` prefixed accesses. This is correct, that Cecil considers it part of the type name is not correct (but that it is part of the type could be considered "correct" insofar as you really do need to know this if you generate access opcodes, so yeah).

Comment: To be precise -- the type of `field` really is `T[] modreq(IsVolatile)`, as the `modreq` modifier is part of the type, but of course trying to use this as the full type *name* is not correct/will fail, as it's a type based on `T[]`, where `T` is the first generic parameter of the class (which is what the `!0` means; on the IL level type parameters have no names other than for pretty-printing). In "normal" reflection, this is exposed not through `Type` but through `FieldInfo.GetRequiredCustomModifiers()`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for your reply. Out of curiosity I tried to reproduce the error with a class that contains `public volatile int[] field`, but I was unable to. Type resolution succeeded, and no `ResolutionException` was thrown. Based on your explanation, I had expected to encounter the same error. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: No -- that just demonstrates that apparently, the bug (if it is a bug, it might just be a an API restriction or misuse, which I can't really judge since I have little experience with Cecil) is restricted to generic types (or possibly even arrays of generic types). The resolve logic apparently does not stumble over `modreq(Volatile)` *in general*. You should look at how `ResolveTypeReference` is getting called -- I can easily imagine attempting to resolve "the type" of a field of an open generic type (`C<>`) to fail this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up working around this by checking to see if the type I was resolving was a RequiredModifierType before doing the resolve and resolving on it's element type if it was of that type.

```
if (tr is RequiredModifierType)
    tr = tr.GetElementType();
var td = tr.Resolve();
```

There isn't much (any?) documentation but it seems like Cecil surfaces the volatile modifier as an enclosing type.  Resolving on that will always fail as far as I can tell.